# XtraReports Not working in V11.2.8 Version

Tags: devexpress

Currently i am using Devexpress XtraReports V11.2.8. My problem is i am able to populate report in V11.1.6 but i am unable to populate report in V11.2.8 it showing only scroll bar in the reportviewer when i debug it is properly mapping and binding the data. FYI: I need to bind/Initialize  reportviewer in button click only. Devexpress people said that i need to initialize reportviewer with the report in  page_load it self but we can't do that because we have large amount of data exist and we need to populate report with particular input criteria matched result only. Please advice.

FYI: refer this link for devexpress response on the above issue  http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q362696

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any solution about version problem without additional information.

but, the 2nd problem you told, i can give a possible solution to that. You can take necessary input you need for the report and then click on the button to preview the report regarding on inputs. It is better to create a stored procedure in your database for this report.

Suppose, you need to show a report for specific 'Cust_Id'. In the **'Form1'** put a text field for 'Cust_Id' and  a 'button'. On button click event put the following code,

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Portfolio_XtraReport port = new Portfolio_XtraReport();
            string custID = textEdit1.Text.ToString();
            port.Portfolio(custID);
            port.ShowPreview();
        }
```

now in the **'Portfolio_XtraReport.cs'** put the following code,

```
public Portfolio_XtraReport()
        {
            Portfolio("N");
        }
        public void Portfolio(string custId)
        {
            if (custId != "N")
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                sP_PORTFOLIOTableAdapter.GetData(custId);

            }
        }
```

Here, **sP_PORTFOLIOTableAdapter** is the table adapter for the dataset, I used a stored procedure which takes 'Cust_Id' as input.